# Can I always use `||` to assign default parameter values?

Tags: javascript, operators, default-parameters

### Optional Parameters

I often have JavaScript functions with optional parameters.
Instead of writing a long check like this:

```
if(param === null || param === undefined){ 
    param = {};
}
```

I usually use the following syntax:

```
function doSomething(optionalParam, optionalCallback, optionalFlag){
    optionalParam = optionalParam || {};
    optionalParam["xyz"] = "value";    //Won't fail if the user didn't pass a value

    optionalCallback = optionalCallback || function(){};
    optionalCallback();        //If I need the function on 20 places, I don't have to insert a typeof-check everywhere

    optionalFlag = optionalFlag || false;
}
```

The advantages are clear and I can deal with both `undefined` and `null` parameters.

This will, however, not work for optional flags that default to true:

```
someFlag = someFlag || true; //Will never evaluate to false.
```

### Return values

Here's another example where I use that syntax:

```
function getValueOfIndex(idx){
    return anArray[idx] || null;  //Returns null if the index is out of bounds
}
```

### My Question:

**How does the `||` operator work in my use case?**

- Can I use `||` for all of these situations?
- Is there any reason not to use it?
- Are there any other types or values where this syntax will fail?

**Edit:** I recognised that my last point (difference between `null||undefined` and `undefined||null`) should belong to a seperate question, so I removed it.

Comment: You'd do well to research "falsy" and "truthy" values in Javascript. Both `null` and `undefined` are falsy, that's why you get the behaviors listed at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work when the default is `true`? if `someFlag` isn't set yet, `someFlag || true` will return `true`, which is the correct default.

Comment: @Barmar If the user passes `false`, `false || true` will always evaluate to true.

Comment: I think Maja means that you can't set defaults for bool inputs in this way. If the user passes `false`, the check will always convert it to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is that you can't use

```
parameter = parameter || default;
```

if the user should be able to pass an explicit parameter that's falsey, and that should take precedence over the default. In that case you need to test explicitly for `undefined`:

```
parameter = typeof parameter == "undefined" ? default : parameter;
```

If the user should be able to pass an explicit `undefined` value and have that take precedence (a very perverse thing to do), you'll need to test `arguments.length` to determine how many arguments were passed, so you can default only the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Why do the following two expression return different values?

- null || undefined  //evaluates to undefined
- undefined || null  //evaluates to null

something || somethingElse is an expression, meaning it will **always** return a value, either the first truthy value, otherwise the last value at all. For example `false || 17` is 17. Both null and undefined are falsy, so in both cases, || will return the last value.

Can I use || for all of these situations?

|| Can sometimes do something you wouldn't expect

```
function thisIsUnexpected (a) {
    a = a || "other value";
    reurn a;
}

thisIsUnexpected(); // will return "other value";
// it can fail when you pass in a falsy value
thisIsUnexpected(false); // you would want it to return false, yet it will return "other value"
```

To get the correct behavior, you'd want to use a ternary expression as follows. This can never fail.

```
function thisIsExpected (a) {
    a = (a === undefined) ? "other value" : a;
    reurn a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR operator can be used **as long as the expression used to test for the presence of an argument returns true for all the cases where an argument is supplied**.

```
someFlag = someFlag || true; //Will never evaluate to false.
```

Your example above doesn't work because I can supply the argument `false` and the expression used to test for the presence of an argument (in this case simply `someFlag`) will still evaluate to false, implying that an argument was not specified.

So you would need to modify the code to something like:

```
someFlag = (typeof someFlag === 'boolean') ? someFlag : true;
```